# How to determine what the Seemingly Unrelated Regression (SUR) error means in R

Tags: r, regression

I am using the `systemfit()` function to conduct a seemingly unrelated regression (SUR) and am getting the following error:

```
Error in solve(sigma, tol = solvetol) : 
Lapack routine dsptrf returned error code 1
```

Yet, I'm unable to find the meaningful interpretation of what the error suggests is going on. Below is some simulated code that works to show what functions I'm using (the simulated code does not produce an error). Thanks for thoughts on this error.

```
y <- sample(seq(1:4), 100, replace = TRUE)
x1 <- sample(seq(0:1), 100, replace = TRUE) -1
x2 <- sample(seq(0:1), 100, replace = TRUE) - 1
x3 <- sample(seq(1:4), 100, replace = TRUE)
frame <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x1,x2, x3))

mod_1 <- y ~ x1 + x3 + x1:x3
mod_2 <- y ~ x2 + x3 + x2:x3

output <- systemfit(list(mod_1, mod_2), data = frame, method = "SUR")
```

Comment: Check [here](http://www.inside-r.org/questions/seemingly-unrelated-regression). It seems your data have NA values.

Comment: I ran your code without any problems. Are your packages up-to-date? What's your session info?

Comment: See [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/dcd/dsptrf_8f.html) and scroll down to the INFO return value. As it indicates, these LAPACK errors usually mean a matrix factorization failed due to some sort of singularity. This usually is specific to your exact data. Probably no one would be able to diagnose the exact issue without your data.